# How to create the correct database structure to avoid duplicate data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, laravel, database-design

I work with categories in my project. Now my categories database structure is like this:

```
id
title
description
slug
parent_id
```

**Problem**:

I currently have two categories for products. The first category is for "Selling" and the second is for "Buying" products. In the "Sale" category, sellers list their products for sale. And in the "Purchase" category, buyers place some products to buy. In this case, both categories will have the same subcategories. In my table structure, I am duplicating subcategories for both categories like this:

**Sale**

- Bags
- Shoes
- Dress

**Buy**

- Bags
- Shoes
- Dress

**Database**

```
id | title | description | slug | parent_id
-------------------------------------------
1  | Sale  |   null      | sale | null
2  | Bags  |   null      | bags | 1
3  | Shoes |   null      | shoes| 1
4  | Dress |   null      | dress| 1
5  | Buy   |   null      | buy  | null
6  | Bags  |   null      | bags | 2
7  | Shoes |   null      | shoes| 2
8  | Dress |   null      | dress| 2
-------------------------------------------
```

How do I create the correct table structure to avoid duplicate subcategories in my case?

I have tables `products` and `categories` only now.

Comment: Does the subcategory have children within or it is limited to category and subcategory?

Comment: If the {Selling, Buying} aspect and  the "subcategories" aspect are idependent why you need a list of combinations in the DB?

Comment: @danish-khan-I All subcategories has children in my case

Comment: @Serg What do you recommend to solve the problem with another way?

Comment: DB/SQL designs for subtypes is a faq.

Comment: Why have two categories (buy/sell)?  Add to your example a case where they are not the same.  I can't even see why you have 8 rows instead of simply 3 (bags, shoes, dress).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all, you **don't necessarily** need to have two separate categories for selling / buying.

because if you do such a thing, the only way you can have exactly same subcategories is to **mirror** them (create, edit, delete 2 times everywhere in your code)

One other solution is to have **a pivot table** so your subcategories can have multiple parents (many-to-many relationship)

but if you want to stick to simple one-to-many relationship I suggest making one general parent category and use it twice in your menu once for selling and once for buying.

**edit:**
Your migration will look like this in case you want to take many-to-many approach:

```
Schema::create('category_relations', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id');
   $table->unsignedBigInteger('child_id');
});
```

and your model :

```php
Class Category extends Model{
    public function parents(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class,'category_relations','child_id','parent_id');
    }

    public function children(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class,'category_relations','parent_id','child_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: I too think a many-to-many relationship is probably the correct way to do this assuming the subcategories are semantically identical whether they are for buying or selling.